# TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str, Firebase database problem

Tags: python, firebase, typeerror

Im new to coding and I am creating an app that uses firebase to register the data of the user. I'm attempting to update the friend id number of the user once created but I get this error, can someone help me fix this?

Python code

```
friend_patch_data = '{"next_friend_id": %s}' % str(my_friend_id+1)

friend_patch_req = requests.patch("https://the-notebook-196cb.firebaseio.com/.json?auth=" + idToken,
                         data=friend_patch_data)
```

data I am uploading:

```
my_data = '{"Avatar": "bruh.png", "Friends": "", "Notebooks": "", "my_friend_id": %s}'% my_friend_id
```

Error I Get,

> TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Comment: When asking about code that produces an Exception, always include the complete Traceback in the question. Copy the Traceback and paste it in the question, then format it as code (select it and type ctrl-k)

Comment: Often if you search with the error message - `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str` - You'll get plenty of results to sift through and give you an idea of what the problem might be.

Answer (score 0):

When you assign `my_data`, you are saying `my_friend_id` is a string, which it seems it's not.

Use `%d` in the format string:

```
my_data = '{"Avatar": "bruh.png", "Friends": "", "Notebooks": "", "my_friend_id": %d}' % my_friend_id
```

Or use [str.format()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
my_data = '{{"Avatar": "bruh.png", "Friends": "", "Notebooks": "", "my_friend_id": {0}}}'.format(my_friend_id)
```

If you are using Python 3, you can use f-strings:

```
my_data = f'{{"Avatar": "bruh.png", "Friends": "", "Notebooks": "", "my_friend_id": {my_friend_id}}}'
```